# Progress bar hangs while deleting large files

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added the loading bar in below snippet.It’s worked fine which I have deleted small amount of data(say 30 to 150 mb). But the problem is when I deleted large size of data, the loading bar doesn't get loaded(approx 190mb).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self addloading];
    if(_isProgress)
        return;
    _lastDeleteItemIndexAsked = index;
    NSInteger catalogue_id =[[[_currentData  objectAtIndex:index%[_currentData count]] valueForKey:@"catalogue_id"] integerValue];
    BOOL update_avilable = [[[online_date_array objectAtIndex:index%[_currentData count]] valueForKey:@"update_version"] boolValue];
       if(update_avilable)
        [[self GridViewDelegate] deletecatlogue_for_update:catalogue_id];
    else
        [[self GridViewDelegate] deletecatlogue:catalogue_id];

    [online_date_array replaceObjectAtIndex:index%[online_date_array count] withObject:[NotificationHandler check_online_date_of_catalogue:catalogue_id]];


    [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:index%[_currentData count] withAnimation:GMGridViewItemAnimationFade];

    [self stopLoadingfor_delete];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it *size* or execution *time*?

I'm going to assume that `self` is a UI object. If it is, the block should be:

```
Controller* __weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    Controller* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        ...
    }
    else {
       // self has been deallocated in the meantime.
    }
});
```

Thus you may prefer a **MVVC** solution, where a view model does the hard work, not the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response.this is the overflow problem.So i have changed the datatype NSInteger to double.Finally, i fixed that issue.  :)

Comment: What about @Lumialxk solution and your comment "No luck, the issue still persists" ?